# how to import json and rendering in three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

Hi everyone i write code for importing a json file and rendering it with three.js i export the json file from [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/)
it doesnt show any error in console

```
window.onload = function(){
var 
    shapeObjectUrl = "test.json",
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new     THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

loader.load( shapeObjectUrl, 
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        console.log(geometry, materials);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
        scene.add( mesh );
        console.log(mesh);
        render();
});

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

};
```

Json file:

```
{
"metadata": {
    "version": 4,
    "type": "geometry",
    "generator": "GeometryExporter"
},
"vertices": [0,50,20,14.14213562373095,50,14.142135623730951,20,50,1.2246063538223773e-15,14.142135623730951,50,-14.14213562373095,2.4492127076447545e-15,50,-20,-14.14213562373095,50,-14.142135623730955,-20,50,-3.673819061467132e-15,-14.142135623730955,50,14.142135623730947,-4.898425415289509e-15,50,20,0,-50,20,14.14213562373095,-50,14.142135623730951,20,-50,1.2246063538223773e-15,14.142135623730951,-50,-14.14213562373095,2.4492127076447545e-15,-50,-20,-14.14213562373095,-50,-14.142135623730955,-20,-50,-3.673819061467132e-15,-14.142135623730955,-50,14.142135623730947,-4.898425415289509e-15,-50,20,0,50,0,0,-50,0],
"normals": [0.3826834323650897,0,0.9238795325112866,0,0,1,0.7071067811865475,0,0.7071067811865476,0.9238795325112866,0,0.3826834323650899,1,0,6.123031769111886e-17,0.9238795325112866,0,-0.38268343236508967,0.7071067811865476,0,-0.7071067811865475,0.3826834323650899,0,-0.9238795325112866,1.2246063538223773e-16,0,-1,-0.3826834323650895,0,-0.9238795325112868,-0.7071067811865474,0,-0.7071067811865476,-0.9238795325112866,0,-0.38268343236508984,-1,0,-1.836909530733566e-16,-0.9238795325112868,0,0.3826834323650895,-0.7071067811865478,0,0.7071067811865475,-0.38268343236508995,0,0.9238795325112866,-2.4492127076447545e-16,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,0],
"uvs": [[0,1,0,0,0.125,1,0.125,0,0.25,1,0.25,0,0.375,1,0.375,0,0.5,1,0.5,0,0.625,1,0.625,0,0.75,1,0.75,0,0.875,1,0.875,0,1,1,1,0]],
"faces": [56,0,9,1,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,56,9,10,1,1,3,2,0,1,2,2,56,1,10,2,2,3,4,3,2,2,4,56,10,11,2,3,5,4,3,2,4,4,56,2,11,3,4,5,6,5,4,4,6,56,11,12,3,5,7,6,5,4,6,6,56,3,12,4,6,7,8,7,6,6,8,56,12,13,4,7,9,8,7,6,8,8,56,4,13,5,8,9,10,9,8,8,10,56,13,14,5,9,11,10,9,8,10,10,56,5,14,6,10,11,12,11,10,10,12,56,14,15,6,11,13,12,11,10,12,12,56,6,15,7,12,13,14,13,12,12,14,56,15,16,7,13,15,14,13,12,14,14,56,7,16,8,14,15,16,15,14,14,16,56,16,17,8,15,17,16,15,14,16,16,56,0,1,18,0,2,3,17,17,17,17,56,1,2,18,2,4,5,17,17,17,17,56,2,3,18,4,6,7,17,17,17,17,56,3,4,18,6,8,9,17,17,17,17,56,4,5,18,8,10,11,17,17,17,17,56,5,6,18,10,12,13,17,17,17,17,56,6,7,18,12,14,15,17,17,17,17,56,7,8,18,14,16,17,17,17,17,17,56,10,9,19,3,1,0,18,18,18,18,56,11,10,19,5,3,2,18,18,18,18,56,12,11,19,7,5,4,18,18,18,18,56,13,12,19,9,7,6,18,18,18,18,56,14,13,19,11,9,8,18,18,18,18,56,15,14,19,13,11,10,18,18,18,18,56,16,15,19,15,13,12,18,18,18,18,56,17,16,19,17,15,14,18,18,18,18]
}
```

i appreciate any help

Comment: just wanted to know , that you want to show the exported object inside the threejs editor itself of your own threejs code.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method you are using is right except for some minor things like, in `loader.load` function's call back you are trying to access material also but its not included in the JSON .

Now I used your code and was successfully able to load the JSON object, so there is nothing wrong with that, except that you are setting camera position to 5 which just makes the loaded model out of the view.

So you can reposition the model like this

```
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load( 'models/jsonModel.json', function ( geometry ) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );

                        mesh.position.x =500;
                        mesh.position.y =100;
                        mesh.position.z =500;
        scene.add( mesh );

        });
```

or set the `camera` position to some other position.

You can also use `OrbitControls` to instead.

Including the above mentioned things I have created a sample code [here](http://metalop.com/threejs/test.html), you can look are lines 138 and 62, to understand better.

Comment: @user3340330 : you are most welcomed :) . If you found the answer helpful,  you can even upvote it. :)

Comment: I set camera position to 1000, mesh position to 0 0 0 but it doesn't appear. I copied the original poster's json model. The scene renders but the mesh is not displayed.

Comment: @SWA: its a very old answer, the model or Three.js APIs might have also changed. Please check the official docs, if it still dosen't work you can open a new question too.

Comment: @Shiva, I have a new discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112309/using-three-js-exporter-and-json-loader-correctly. Maybe you have an idea about it